What tribe is Avner from?
From what tribe was Avner, he was not fond of the tribe of Yehuda. In the book of Shmuel, Avner said to Ish Boshet, "Am I a dog leader to Yehuda?"

Samuel 1:14:51-52 indicates Avner's father Ner was the brother of King Saul's father Kish, both sons of Aviel. Chronicles 1:8:33 indicates Ner was Kish's father. Either way he was presumably a Benjaminite like King Saul.

Wikipedia cites an odd and obscure tradition that Avner actually was the child of a relationship between Noah's son Shem and his great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-grandson Abraham's daughter Bakol. If so I guess he's not from any tribe? And he lived to at least 1200 years old?

...and not Jewish?

@AKA If he converted at Har Sinai he could be Jewish. Although I think the best that could be said for that Medrash (not one of the accepted ones) is that it is metaphorical somehow.
